# How to implement a horizontally sliding navbar that overlaps other unrelated links

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

Im trying to create a sliding navigation menu using JQuery. The idea is that I will have two or more main sections and each section will have several subsections.

When a user hovers over one section, the subsections will expand horizontally and if another section was currently open and showing its subsections, it will collapse back to just show the main section.

I have implemented some basic code to expand the width of a section as follows.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Section 1
$('#S1Hover').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    if ($('#S2wrapper').is(":visible")){
        $('#S2wrapper').animate({width: 0})
    }
    $('#S1wrapper').animate({width: 400})
});

// Section 2
$('#S2Hover').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    if ($('#S1wrapper').is(":visible")){
        $('#S1wrapper').animate({width: 0})
    }
    $('#s2wrapper').animate({width: '300'});
});   
});
```

The HTML for this is

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="S1Hover" class="event">Section 1</div>
    <div id="S1wrapper">
    <ul id="S1">
        <li id="SS1"><a href="#">SS1</a></li>
        <li id="SS2"><a href="#">SS2</a></li>
        <li id="SS3"><a href="#">SS3</a></li>
        <li id="SS4"><a href="#">SS4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="S2Hover" class="event">S2</div>
    <div id="S2wrapper">
    <ul id="projects-nav">
        <li id="SS5"><a href="#">SS5</a</li>
        <li id="SS6"><a href="#">SS6</a></li>
        <li id="SS7"><a href="#">SS7</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It currently doesnt really do anything though and would appreciate any help with this. Also, if I do get this working, is there any browser specific things to watch out for ?

EDIT: I failed to mention that when a Section has been expanded, I would like it to stay in that state until a different section has been hovered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is that whatever you want to hover will need to be placed inside the element that starts the hovering.  For example if you want #S2Wrapper to hover its contents inside then you will need to do wrap it around the element.

```
<div id="S2Wrapper">
 <div class="hover-stuff">
  <ul>
   <li>This is hovered</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

You will then hid the .hover-stuff and only display it whenever S2Wrapper is hovered.  Also you will probably want to position S2Wrapper relative and hover-stuff absolute to the length and width you want.

The reason is that the S2Wrapper is the element being hovered, whenever its not being hovered anymore and the menu drops then it will just go back up.

Comment: Sorry something I failed to mention... When you hover over a section and it expands then remove the mouse, I intended it to stay in an expanded state until a different section was hovered

Comment: For that you would make the dropdown visible on hover but do not make it disappear whenever you leave the hover.  Then you could use a jquery $("div").each(function(){} and I would give each hover down class an additional class name that you will make disappear when the new section is hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

Without change your DOM structure too much you could try the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="S1Hover" class="event">Section 1</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="S1">
    <li id="SS1"><a href="#">SS1</a></li>
    <li id="SS2"><a href="#">SS2</a></li>
    <li id="SS3"><a href="#">SS3</a></li>
    <li id="SS4"><a href="#">SS4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="S2Hover" class="event">S2</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="projects-nav">
    <li id="SS5"><a href="#">SS5</a</li>
    <li id="SS6"><a href="#">SS6</a></li>
    <li id="SS7"><a href="#">SS7</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper ul{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .wrapper ul li{
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        margin-right:6px;
        width:0;
        height:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('.event').hover(function () {
            $(this).next().find('li').animate({width:80}, 750);
        }, function () {
            $(this).next().find('li').animate({ width: 0 }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

I would give the wrapper a class instead of an id on each one. Also I have a hard-coded value of 80px as a width and 20px as a height for each `<li>` section, you can change this to whatever fits your content.